# What path for file with configurations of AWS EMR stored in S3 should be?

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I want to load json file from s3 to --configuration parameter of create cluster command.
The error I catch is:

> aws: error: invalid json argument for option --configurations

Passing my json locally works, hense my json file without mistakes.

I made my s3 bucket public and it didn`t help me

The path I tried to use is:

```
https://<bucketname>.s3.amazonaws.com/<filename>
```

How propper path to my s3 file should look for passing it to command?

Full command I use is:

```
aws emr create-cluster 
--name task5-emr \
--use-default-roles \
--configurations <path to s3 json file> \
--release-label emr-6.3.1 \
--instance-count 2 \
--instance-type m3.xlarge \
--applications Name=Spark Name=Hadoop \
--ec2-attributes KeyName=<my key>\
```

My json file looks like:

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "yarn-site",
    "Properties": {
      "yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class": "org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler"
    },
    "Configurations": []
  },
  {
    "Classification": "spark-defaults",
    "Properties": {
      "spark.scheduler.mode": "FAIR",
      "spark.scheduler.allocation.file": "/etc/hadoop/conf/fairscheduler.xml"
    },
    "Configurations": []
  }
]
```

Comment: Have you found any answer? My aws cli for emr started suddenly giving this error!

Comment: @Maziyar If I am not mistaken, the issue was that my pc did not have have permissions to interact with S3. So i just loaded it from my pc

Comment: Thanks @chugaister appreciate the update. I myself ended up just putting that file on an S3 where it had to be public.

I am using Terraform now which I can just pass an actual JSON content without having the file on an S3 though